# How to make fixed background to cover entire screen in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am using following CSS hack

```
html { 
    background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But when using mobile browsers , the height is of website is not covering the entire screen display ! what to do ??

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the page the full height/width of the screen.

```
html,
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This helped me , also you can enclose your content in a div after a body tag and set its width and height to 100%.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. I would recommend adding another `<div>` to enclose the background image.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying the height and width, note that "background-attachment: fixed" is not supported in some mobile browsers. See the full [browser support list](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) (click the "known issues" tab at the bottom).

One way to work around this on mobile (but continue using "fixed" for other browsers) is to revert to "background-attachment: scroll" for mobile widths using a media query. For example:

If your original CSS was

```
#some-div
{
     background: url("background.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

Then your media query might look like this:

```
@media (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 767px) 
{
    #some-div {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you don't need "background-attachment: fixed" in the first place, then just removing "fixed" from your first line might help.